# taking a passcode value from user, i want to use this passcode in url path, i am using thymeleaf as template engine

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, template-engine

I have an problem about that taking a passcode value from user, i want to use this passcode in url path, i am using thymeleaf as template engine.

This is my controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/findEvent/{passcode}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String findEvent(@PathVariable("passcode") String passcode,
                            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model) {

        Event event=eventService.findByPassCode(passcode);
        List<Question> questions=questionService.findQuestionsByPasscode(passcode);

        model.addAttribute("questions",questions);

        return "questions";
    }
```

and these is my html pages

addEvent.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" th:action="@{/eventSave}" th:object="${eventRegister}">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{eventName}"><br>
    Passcode:<br>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{eventPasscode}"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

passcode.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" th:action="@{/findEvent/{passcode}}">

    Passcode:<br>
    <input type="text"  th:text="*{passcode}" ><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

questions.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-12">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Question </th>
            <th>Votes </th>

        </tr>
        <tr th:each="questions : ${questions}" th:object="${question}">
            <td th:text="*{text} "></td>
            <td th:text="*{voteValue} "></td>

            <a th:href="@{/voteQuestion/{id} (id=${question.questionId})}">Vote the question</a>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[and this is my result http://localhost:8080/findEvent/%7Bpasscode%7D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV3hC.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form action URL to contain a value from the form itself, then you need an `onSubmit` handler to update the URL from the form field.

Form values are only included automatically in the *body* of a `POST` request, or as *query parameters* of a `GET` request.

Anything else you have to do with JavaScript code.

Comment: I can't send this value into the controller even if I don't use it in url. Do you have an idea about this

Comment: @MihriNurGürün Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Why can't you post the value to the controller? By any means?